# What test (null hypothesis) does a model's `f_pvalue` correspond to?

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

What is the null hypothesis behind an `OLSResults`'s `f_pvalue` attribute? [This docstring](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.f_pvalue.html) is not particularly useful.

At first I thought the null hypothesis was that all estimated coefficients are simultaneously zero (including the constant term). However, I am starting to think that the hypothesis being tested is that all estimated parameters **except for the constant term** are simultaneously zero (i.e. *b1 = b2 = ... = bp = 0*, excluding *b0*).

For example, suppose `y` is an array of targets and `X` is a numpy matrix of features (a constant term and *p* features).

```py
# Silly example
from statsmodels.api import OLS
m = OLS(endog=y, exog=X).fit()

# What is being tested here?
print(m.f_pvalue)
```

Does anyone know what the null hypothesis is?

Comment: Your second thought is correct. f_pvalue is for the test that all **slope** coefficients are zero, i.e. comparing the full model to a model with only a constant.

Comment: if there is not constant in the model, then it will be NaN, IIRC

Comment: https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.fvalue.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Josef for clearing things up. As per [the documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.fvalue.html):

> F-statistic of the fully specified model.
>
> Calculated as the mean squared error of the model divided by the mean squared error of the residuals if the nonrobust covariance is used. Otherwise computed using a Wald-like quadratic form that tests whether all coefficients (excluding the constant) are zero.

And just to prove that this is the case:

```py
# Libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.api import OLS
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

# Load target
y = pd.DataFrame(load_boston()['target'], columns=['price'])

# Load features
X = pd.DataFrame(load_boston()['data'], columns=load_boston()['feature_names'])

# Add constant
X['CONST'] = 1

# One feature
m1 = OLS(endog=y, exog=X[['CONST','CRIM']]).fit()
print(f'm1 pvalue: {m1.f_pvalue}')

# Multiple features
m2 = OLS(endog=y, exog=X[['CONST','CRIM','AGE']]).fit()
print(f'm2 pvalue: {m2.f_pvalue}')

# Manually test H0: all coefficients are zero (excluding b0)
print('Manual F-test for m1', m1.f_test(r_matrix=np.matrix([[0,0],[0,1]])),
      'Manual F-test for m2', m2.f_test(r_matrix=np.matrix([[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])),
      sep='\n')

# Output
"""
> m1 pvalue: 1.1739870821944483e-19
> m2 pvalue: 2.2015246345918656e-27
> Manual F-test for m1
> <F test: F=array([[89.48611476]]), p=1.1739870821945733e-19, df_denom=504, df_num=1>
> Manual F-test for m2
> <F test: F=array([[69.51929476]]), p=2.2015246345920063e-27, df_denom=503, > df_num=2>
"""
```

So yes, `f_pvalue` matches the p-value of manually entering the null hypothesis.